# Can I access to enum by [ ]?

Tags: swift, enums

How can I access to enum using [ ] like Numbers["one"]:

```
enum Numbers: String {
  case one = "1"
  case two = "2"
  case three =  "3"
}

print(Numbers["one"])
```

Comment: What do you need that for? Perhaps better use a dictionary instead of an enumeration?

Comment: What are you trying to do with it? Maybe you have the wrong type for the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: So, do you want `Numbers.one` only using different syntax or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let access_num = Numbers.two
print(access_num.rawValue)
// prints "2"
```

or

```
enum Numbers: Int {
 case one = 1, two , three , four
} 

var access_num = Numbers(rawValue: 2)!
print(access_num)
```

Comment: complete code
    enum Numbers: String {
    case one = 1, two , three , four
    }
 
    var access_num = Numbers(rawValue: 2)!
    print(access_num)

Comment: with above method you can access the value dynamically

Comment: @aleksandr-maybach, so what exactly here answers you question?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you mean the rawValue?

```
print(Numbers(rawValue:"1"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access its string value like this :

print(Numbers.one.rawValue) . //output:- "1/n"